# should the function with the following property vanish at some point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ smooth such that $f(x+1,-y) = -f(x,y)$, should the function with this property vanish at some point?

I've tried direct inspection, tried to override one of the coordinates to see if the result was an odd function, but nothing seems to work. Is there any other way to address this problem?

Comment: Am I overlooking something or doesn't this just follow from the Intermediate Value Theorem? (Of course not the 1D one but rather a generalized one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \equiv 0$, then we are done. Otherwise, there exists some $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y) \neq 0$. In particular, $f(x,y)$ and $f(x+1,-y)$ have opposite signs. Since $f$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, $\operatorname{im}{f}$ is connected (this is the general version of the IVT) and therefore $0 \in \operatorname{im}{f}$.

Comment: I understood, I had completely forgotten to try with the IVT. Thank you for your help.